# Almost sure convergence of generalized random harmonic series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

**Problem.** Prove that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} \cos(2 \pi \cdot2^{n^2} x)$$
converges for almost every $x \in [0, 1]$ (with Lebesgue measure).

(Credits to B. Tsirelson.)

*My partial solution.* I can apply the Kolmogorov Three-Series theorem to the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} \cos(2 \pi Y_n)$$
where
$$Y_n = [ 2^{n^2} x ] - \frac{[2^{(n+1)^2} x]}{2^{2n + 1}}$$
$$[y] = y - \lfloor y \rfloor$$
Then each $Y_n$ is a function of the $n^2$ till $(n+1)^2 - 1$ binary digits of $x$ and thus independent variables.

Now, the problem is that I do not know how to imply the convergence of the series in question. Is it some series comparison test? Unfortunately the terms of the series change signs... and all relevant theorems we studied can't be applied to the original series because they assume the terms are independent, which is not the case.

Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like I totally forgot about Cauchy convergence criterion, which implies the following which is not mentioned on the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests):

> If $a_n \leq b_n \leq c_n$ are arbitrary reals, $\sum a_n$ and $\sum c_n$ converging series, then $\sum b_n$ is also converging.

This follows from
$$\left| \sum_m^n b_k \right| \leq \max \left\{ \left| \sum_m^n a_k \right|, \left| \sum_m^n c_k \right| \right\}$$
and Cauchy criterion applied.

Now, in the original question, we have:

$$\frac{1}{n} \cos(2\pi Y_n) - \frac{1}{n2^{2n + 1}} \leq \frac{1}{n}\cos(2\pi \cdot 2^{n^2} x) \leq \frac{1}{n} \cos(2 \pi Y_n)$$